# Magento Layout Empty, header and footer showing

Tags: magento

I am Creating Page CMS  Pages and set empty Layout. and under content i added this content

```
{{block type="catalog/product_view" product_id="797" template="catalog/product/view/bundle_color.phtml"}}
```

and my bundle_color.phtml containts simple Hello

But it is showing header and footer as well. I dnt want header and footer.

Can  any  body tell me how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove header and footer from layout section

just go to cms>you_page>Design

In Layout Update XML just

```
<remove name="header"/> 
<remove name="footer"/>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Element 'remove': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, container, move, uiComponent )